# App performance issue or phone's performance issue

Tags: android, performance

I work at a phone manufacturer (OEM).

One of our preloaded third-party apps has been complained about by our users that the performance is very bad on our mid-to-low end devices.

Without having access to the app's source code, how do I determine whether the performance problem is caused mostly by how the app was written or by the limitation of the device (e.g. CPU)?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. Even though it should require code.

My take;

When it comes to performance especially when it comes to Android, the issue always has to do with application development.

If an application is struggling, regardless of its capabilities, it is trying to do too much at once. There are many ways to improve performance with asynchronous background threads, and with modern development Croutines.

People complain about performance for one reason. The application is showing the user it is struggling. If you are working on low end devices, your views should be very simple and clean, and data/views should be asynchronous to prevent too too much from happening at one time.